# How to handle session information in an Asp.net MVC app with dependency injection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, dependency-injection

I have a multitenant application where I want to keep track of two things across the app: The user and The tenant.

I have this three cases:

1. Anonymous Users: In this case **user** is null, and **tenant** is tracked by querystring.
2. Authenticated Users: **user** comes from cookie, **tenant** is saved in session.
3. Jobs: I have jobs in my app to do some work, the **user** in this case is null and the **tenant** is set manually.

In all my services I use the user and the tenant.

I tought at first of using an object per http session in my DI container, but this wouldn't work with the Jobs.

Any toughts on how can I handle this information, I'm currently using it in a Session variable, but I have many problems with this implementation, and I need to have a lot of special cases to handle jobs and unauthenticated users.

Comment: Are you using a DI library? If so, which one?

Comment: I'm not using any at this moment, but I was looking to use Simple Injector

Comment: Make tenant first segment of your route, followed by controller and action. This is very flexible and should solve all your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least you should do is abstracting access to user context. For instance:

```
public interface IUserContext {
    IPrincipal User { get; }
    Tenant Tenant { get; }
}
```

You might want to have a separate `ITenantContext` abstraction, but let's stick to one for now.

Your system will probably have two applications: windows service that runs the jobs, and a web application that handles user interaction. Both applications have their own entry point, their own [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), and their own unique DI configuration.

For the web application, I imagine the implementation to look as follows:

```
public AspNetUserContext : IUserContext
{
    private readonly ITenantRepository tenantRepository;

    public AspNetUserContext(ITenantRepository tenantRepository) {
        this.tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
    }

    public IPrincipal User {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User; }
    }

    public Tenant Tenant {
        get { 
            if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                return this.tenantRepository.GetByName(
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["tenant"]);
            } else {
                return this.tenantRepository.GetByName(
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["tenant"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the job service, things might look completely diffetent at first, but with the service, the processing of one job can be considered a request. So that means that when the request start, you need to set the context (something that ASP.NET does for us in the backgroudn). The `IUserContext` might look as follows:

```
public JobServiceUserContext : IUserContext
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static IPrinciple user;

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Tenant tenant;

    public IPrincipal User { 
        get { return this.user; }
        set { this.user = user; }
    }

    public IPrincipal User { 
        get { return this.tenant; }
        set { this.tenant = tenant; }
    }
}
```

Now the execution of a job can be wrapped with some logic that sets the proper context, for instance:

```
public class JobRunner {
    private readonly JobServiceUserContext context;
    private readonly IJobDactory jobFactory;
    public JobServiceUserContext(JobServiceUserContext context,
        IJobDactory jobFactory) {
        this.context = context;
        this.jobFactory = jobFactory;
    }

    public void RunJob(JobDetails job) {
        try {
            this.context.User = job.User;
            this.context.Tenant = job.Tenant;

            IJob job = this.jobFactory.Create(job.Type);

            job.Execute(job.Data);

            Activator.CreateInsta
        } finally {
            // Reset
            this.context.Tenant = null;
            this.context.User = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In case they are both running within the same application, and the jobs are running on a background thread, you can introduce a proxy implementation for `IUserContext` that transparently switches to the right implementation. For instance:

```
public SelectingUserContextProxy : IUserContext {
    private readonly Func<bool> selector;
    private readonly IUserContext trueContext;
    private readonly IUserContext falseContext;
    public SelectingUserContextProxy(Func<bool> selector,
        IUserContext trueContext, IUserContext falseContext) {
        this.selector = selector;
        this.trueContext = trueContext;
        this.falseContext = falseContext;
    }

    public IPrincipal User { get { return this.Context.User; } }
    public Tenant Tenant { get { return this.Context.Tenant; } }

    private IUserContext Context {
        get { return selector() ? trueContext : falseContext; }
    }
}
```

And you can register this as follows:

```
var jobContext = new JobServiceUserContext();

container.RegisterSingle<IUserContext>(
    new SelectingUserContextProxy(
        () => HttpContext.Current != null,
        trueContext: new AspNetUserContext(),
        falseContext: jobContext));
```

Comment: What if my jobs are in the same application? I'm using Quartz.net to schedule jobs. How should I configure DI ?